# Fixed Sidebar in zurb foundation

Tags: css-position, zurb-foundation, sidebar

I am building a site using the [foundation 4.0 framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

and I would like a fixed sidebar, similar to the [Bootstrap Affix](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix) functionality.

Here is my example, I would like the right habd div.panel to be fixed. Fixing it via CSS however breaks the structure.

Has anyone done anything like this before? I've had a look at the Magellan addon to see if I can make sense of it but it looks like a different animal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Magellan is your best bet if you want to stick with foundation only.
While it isn't exactly the same it can be customized to provide similar functionality.
In this [issue tracker](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/822), awshout posts a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64DHX/) as an example of a sticky sidebar.
In the fiddle, he uses the tab class with his navigation.

```
<ul class="magellan tabs vertical" data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
  <li data-magellan-arrival="grid"><a href="#grid">Grid</a></li>
  <li data-magellan-arrival="tabs"><a href="#tabs">Tabs</a></li>
  <li data-magellan-arrival="buttons"><a href="#buttons">Buttons</a></li>
</ul>
```

There's also some other good information in the tracker if you want a fixed side nav as well as a fixed header.

Other than Magellan, you could try to use a third party plugin like [stickyMojo.js](http://mojotech.github.io/stickymojo/)

Comment: The stickymojo link is now dead.

Comment: The stickymojo link is now back alive.(Should I believe in reincarnation now?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try building your own floating navigation. This code works for me:

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {        

    $("#floatingNav").css("z-index", "99999").css("right", "0").css("position", "absolute");

    // get initial top offset of navigation 
    var floating_navigation_offset_top = $('#floatingNav').offset().top;

    // define the floating navigation function
    var floating_navigation = function(){

        // current vertical position from the top
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        // if scrolled more than the navigation, change its 
        // position to fixed to float to top, otherwise change 
        // it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > floating_navigation_offset_top) { 
            $('#floatingNav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'right': $('h4.titleImage').offset().left, 'width': 158 });
        } else {
            $('#floatingNav').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'right':0, 'width':158 }); 
        }   
    };

    // run function on load
    floating_navigation();

    // run function every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        floating_navigation();
    });
});
```

Add that to your custom js file and give the navigation `floatingNav` id

Source: [How to Build a Floating Navigation Bar](http://liljosh.com/how-to-build-a-floating-navigation-when-scrolling/)

PS: I have added a couple of lines to the original code, so that the width of the sidebar doesn't change. Remove/change it the way your prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Foundation provides you with the fixed class.  Just wrap your side nav in a div using the fixed class

```
<div id="nav" class="fixed">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can then specify in your css the height you want it from the top or position to the left.

```
#nav {
  top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen a fixed class within Foundation. It's not within their Global CSS mixins for v4 - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/global.html are you sure you're not thinking of TopBar which has an option for Fixed?

Comment: Not in their global mixins but they have the class for use with their sticky top nav. https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/34fd64ff1e18b965d9c3de38515e43e7b1b1f2cb/scss/foundation/components/_top-bar.scss#L88